# Large list of objects in OOP?

Tags: php, oop

So I think the usual way for printing lists of object is to have some Collection Class or something that returns the ids of the objects you want to list, then you initiate an object for every id, and then list them.

Is that really the best way to do this ?
This means that in the background you do one DB query to get the ids, then an other DB query for every object when initiating.

Sure, this is no problem when working with small lists. But in large lists, this means heavy DB load, no ?

Is there a better way to do this ?

( I hope this is not a stupid question ... rather new to OOP ;)

EDIT:

Ok, so sorry if this was not clear enough. ( maybe because I approach this all wrong )
Let's say I have a table with all my products. Now I want to list them all ... but I need some data transformation before outputting the product properties to the list. This data transformation is (normally) handled by the product object.

Stupid example:

```
$product->replaceBadWordsInDescription();
```

Now, in order to be able to use these functions in my list, I need to have an product object instance for every product in the list, right ?

I think the flyweight pattern could be a way. I will read into it.

2ND EDIT:

I tried to reduce my question to be specific. ( using the list example ) But in general, when working with many objects of the same class, is it best practice to initiate every object and use it's constructor ( or by factory ) to populate it's properties from DB, or is there a better way ?

Wouldn't it be less resource consuming to have one query returing ALL the properties for all the objects we want to create, then pass them to the object initiation ? ( if I understand correctly, this is the idea of the flyweight pattern )

Comment: try this: http://www.sitepoint.com/php-data-structures-1/

Comment: The first sentence you wrote isn't really correct. You're talking about the *usual* way. What usual way? Where did you read about the usual way? You can easily query the database, use `join` and whatnot to obtain the data set you want to work with which you represent in PHP as series of objects (for ease of working with them). The database load that you mentioned is too ambiguous, databases can handle **a lot**. Without code, without the actual problem - all that's left is to speculate, and that's not what this site is about. Please provide some code so we can move on properly.

Comment: "But in large lists, this means heavy DB load, no ?" - If you really generate heavy load, you surely should worry about the client who has to download huge amounts of html data and not the DB...

Comment: How about saving the product description without bad words? Doing the job *once* is always better than doing the job every time you need to list the product. Therefore, your problem goes away if you remove the bad words *before* you insert the product into the database. In that case, the reading/listing becomes trivial.

Comment: This is just a stupid example to illustrate the idea.

Comment: In that case, you've failed to illustrate the idea.

Comment: I understand that my question was not clear enough. Sorry for that. BUT, your answers did help me. Thank you !

Comment: This is very good question. But unfortunately you got answers from procedura developers. I wonder what is your opinion on this topic now, after four years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not see this as an answer , would be more than hints what to consider**

If you just want to printing lists of data, why useing objects?

Have your ObjectsClass methods that prepare the data or just getter/setter?

Topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

And why pull first a list of ids and then pull each ids data from DB?

Topic: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

In PHP you dont need for any action [like get data of samekind from DB and print it] Objects.

I thing what you want to try, works also with just fetching data from an **unbuffered** mysql query.

Hope that helps a little bit.

If not, you have to explain more about what you really want to do!

EDIT:

> This data transformation is (normally) handled by the product object.
>   Stupid example: \$product->replaceBadWordsInDescription();
>   Now, in order to be able to use these functions in my list, I need to have >an product object instance for every product in the list, right ?

Not really,  you can make one Object that does the transformation. and give the fetch data from the database to that object method, like :

```
$prepared_row = $productTransformator->replaceBadWordsInDescription($fetched_row);
```

The returned **prepared_row** can then be an flyweight object instance with no methods!

Why, if you product object has many methods, you will have lots of memory useage and process to create foreach row an **heavy** object instance.

So make two classes:

One that prepares the given data (Transformator Instance) and one that just holds the data (Flyweight Instance) without any methods.

But i would just handle the data as **arrays** and work with on Object here, the Transformator Instance.

Hope that gives a direction :)

And to keep it simple and right: **flyweight** here in my example just means NO methods in the instance.

Comment: I won't downvote you but you really wrote a lot, some correct, some false.. may I suggest removing the answer until OP explains his problem clearly so that appropriate answer can be given? This way, you may actually convince an innocent person who is learning coding that php is stateless, when in reality it's a general purpose programming language :/

Comment: Ok, will remove the part with **states**. But the sentence **So I think the usual way for printing lists of object ..** is in my opinion not really explaining what the PHP Code should do here! In PHP you can fetch data from db row by row and print it directly.

Comment: You're correct, the OP didn't really provide us with enough information in order to help him. The only thing, I assume, is to wait for more info or forget about this question.

Comment: @ N.B. That is what i tell in my last sentence. **If not, you have to explain more..**.